# German credit dataset : interpretation of checking_status feature

Tags: interpretation, credit-scoring

I am struggling to understand the meaning of some features of the german credit [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/statlog+(german+credit+data)).

I am particularly interested in, the categorical feature checking_status (Status of existing checking account) which has 4 possible values :

- '< 0'
- '0<X<200'
- '>=200'
- 'no checking'

I am not a banking expert but my intuition would be than the higher the checking status the higher the probability to be classified as good. TO check my intuition I computed the proportion of applicant classified as good in the dataset depending on their checking_status values. The results were surprising :

- no checking : 88 %
- <0 : 35 %
- 0<=X<200 : 42 %
- '>=200' : 12 %

Can be read as : 88 % of applicants with 'no checking' are classified as good.

So according to german credit dataset it is harder to have a credit with more money '>=200' < '<0' and it is much easier when the applicant does not have a bank account !

Any idea/links on the interpretation of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

The dataset description was vague, so it's a guess - but I suspect there is a bit of a Base Rate Fallacy/Survivorship Bias at play.

It's easier to have less money in your account, and therefore there are more people with little or no money than people with a lot of money. On the other extreme, people with private swimming pools full of cash don't go applying for credit - they don't need to.

Therefore, the classifier mostly sees a subset of those people who either need **more** money than your average applicant (and so, if they default, you lose more) or burn through the money they do have **faster** (and therefore have a higher risk of defaulting).

There might be some more sociological factors at play, too - you're not seeing all the people who would have had a high-value checking account - if they had one at all, but they chose not to for some reason. I don't feel qualified to speculate on the exact factors at play in 90s-era Germany, though.